# Software for mathematical shapes

Tags: math, graphic-design

I try to find a software or web app which are suitable for mathematical shapes design. I have tried

- Geogebra
- Cabri II
- sketchpad

but all of them have low quality results comparing them with the designs of shapes and figures on school and academic books.

Do you know any software they use on educational books?

Preferable, I want it for Windows or online. I don't have a problem if it is paid or free.

Comment: http://www.blender.org/ , http://mathforum.org/sketchup/ , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sage_(mathematics_software)

Answer (score 2):

Typically textbooks and academic papers use SVG and/or LaTeX, (i.e. postscript), you can try:

- [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/en/) for SVG processing and
- [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41808/how-do-i-install-tex-latex-on-windows-7) answer for LaTeX on Windows.

Both are Free, Open Source, Cross Platform and can produce diagrams suitable for professional printing.