# Mathematical visualization in linux with raytracing

Tags: data-visualization, math, 3d, arch-linux

I am familiar with [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11545/software-for-mathematical-shapes).

I am on Arch linux, and am looking for a software the following features :

- Ability to plot iso and parametric surfaces.
- live preview
- Ability to export in pov-ray compatible files - or any raytracer for the matter
- Hopefully T-Splines

My attempts had been :

Povray itself - very difficult to use, due to no live preview, and trial and error correction for light, camera etc.

Gnuplot to povray - it is confusing for me.

Mathics / Julia - to my knowledge doesn't support povray.

Mayavi - no rendering

So please help with your recommendations.